# How to import modules in sub-packages?

Tags: python, python-import

After restructuring my code I am having trouble importing some modules.

My code structure looks somewhat like the following (both NLTK and pytorch package are within the same package named project).

```
    |------- NLTK_SKLEARN/
    |           |
    |           |----- model/
    |           |          |----__init__.py
    |           |          |----classifier.py
    |           |----train.py          
    |           |
    |------- pytorch/
    |           |
    |           |----- model/
    |           |          |----__init__.py
    |           |          |----classifier.py
    |           |----train.py 
    |           |
```

From each training module I am trying to import the classifier of its sub-package. I have tried a few things and pycharm seems to find all modules, but at execution time I get a module not found error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "NLTK"

What I have tried so far:

```
from NLTK_SKLEARN.model import classifier

from .model.classifier import ClassifierChunker
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you importing `nltk` or `NLTK`?

Comment: At first you have to add an `__init__.py` to every package and sub-package.

Comment: My bad, I have just reviewed my question. There were some mistakes. I am importing my NLTK package and have a  __init__.py module in both model folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports are case sensitive. You should work with lowercase.
Assuming you try to import the lib from the __train.py__ script

```
from model.classifier import *
```

This will pull all defined classes to the __train.py__ runtime.

Comment: Actually that was just a mistake in my question. But the issue seems to have been resolved. I didnt try to import it the "normal" way because pycharm doesnt find the mudules that way, but the execution works. So thanks i guess.